# Asserting a method invocation on one of several injected types

Tags: rhino-mocks, automocking

We use RhinoMocks. I have a type into whose constructor 9 types are injected. I'd like a way of automocking the type, but being able to detect a particular method invocation on one of the injected objects (i.e. I only care about a single method invocation on one of the injected objects).

Is this possible, or do I have to manually inject all the mock objects into the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen any frameworks that would auto-create these mocks for you. You can do it in your [SetUp] method, so at least the tests will not be cluttered with boilerplate code.

Comment: I believe moq supports something like this (auto-mocking or "recursive mocking").

Answer (score 0):

I need to check out http://autofixture.codeplex.com/.  Its not really container specific, there is an extension for rhino mocks.  Disclaimer:  I haven't tried autofixture yet.